# How do I get login token as another user?

Tags: apex

In APEX, I would like to impersonate as someone else in the org and get the security token, is this possible?  I have a connector app setup already and I can already get the login token asmyself but my app also need the security token as other user too, is this possible?

```
public static String getApiAuthenticationToken(){
        AppSettings__c settings = AppSettings__c.getOrgDefaults();
        String clientId =  settings.Callback_Connected_App_Consumer_Key__c;
        String username = UserInfo.getUserName();
        String endpoint = getAuthServerURL();
        String tokenEndpoint = endpoint + '/services/oauth2/token';
        
        Auth.JWT jwt = new Auth.JWT();
        jwt.setSub(username);
        jwt.setAud(endpoint); 
        jwt.setIss(clientId);

        String certName =  settings.Certificate_API_Name__c;

        try{
            Auth.JWS jws = new Auth.JWS(jwt, certName);
            Auth.JWTBearerTokenExchange bearer = new Auth.JWTBearerTokenExchange(tokenEndpoint, jws);
            return bearer.getAccessToken();
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            System.debug(ex);
            return null;
        }

    return null;        
}
```